# AVAssetWriterInput append fails with error code -11800 AVErrorUnknown -12780

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, cvpixelbuffer, avassetwriterinput

I am trying to capture camera video in memory using AVCaptureSession so that I can later write the video data to a movie file. While I have been able to successfully start a capture session, I am not able to successful write the CMSampleBuffers I've captured to a compressed movie file using AVAssetWriter.

Appending sample buffers using AVAssetWriterInput's append method fails and when I inspect the AVAssetWriter's error property, I get the following:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17005d070 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

As far as I can tell -11800 indicates an AVErrorUnknown, however I have not been able to find information about the -12780 error code, which as far as I can tell is undocumented. Below I have pasted the main files in the example project I setup to demonstrate the issue.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    private let recordingClipQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.recordingClipQueue")
    private let videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.videoDataOutputQueue")
    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private var backfillSampleBufferList = [CMSampleBuffer]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480

        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo);
        let videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput;

        do {
            videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating device input from video device: \(error).")
            return
        }

        guard session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
            print("Could not add video device input to capture session.")
            return
        }

        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)

        let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString : Int(kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA) ]
        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)

        guard session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) else {
            print("Could not add video data output to capture session.")
            return
        }

        session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        videoDataOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).isEnabled = true

        session.startRunning()
    }

    private func backfillSizeInSeconds() -> Double {
        if backfillSampleBufferList.count < 1 {
            return 0.0
        }

        let earliestSampleBuffer = backfillSampleBufferList.first!
        let latestSampleBuffer = backfillSampleBufferList.last!

        let earliestSampleBufferPTS = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(earliestSampleBuffer).value
        let latestSampleBufferPTS = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(latestSampleBuffer).value
        let timescale = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(latestSampleBuffer).timescale

        return Double(latestSampleBufferPTS - earliestSampleBufferPTS) / Double(timescale)
    }

    private func createClipFromBackfill() {
        guard backfillSampleBufferList.count > 0 else {
            print("createClipFromBackfill() called before any samples were recorded.")
            return
        }

        let clipURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:
            NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] +
            "/recorded_clip.mp4")

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: clipURL.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: clipURL.path)
            } catch {
                print("Could not delete existing clip file: \(error).")
            }
        }

        var _videoFileWriter: AVAssetWriter?
        do {
            _videoFileWriter = try AVAssetWriter(url: clipURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie)
        } catch {
            print("Could not create video file writer: \(error).")
            return
        }

        guard let videoFileWriter = _videoFileWriter else {
            print("Video writer was nil.")
            return
        }

        let settingsAssistant = AVOutputSettingsAssistant(preset: AVOutputSettingsPreset640x480)!

        guard videoFileWriter.canApply(outputSettings: settingsAssistant.videoSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
            print("Video file writer could not apply video output settings.")
            return
        }

        let earliestRecordedSampleBuffer = backfillSampleBufferList.first!

        let _formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(earliestRecordedSampleBuffer)
        guard let formatDescription = _formatDescription else {
            print("Earliest recording pixel buffer format description was nil.")
            return
        }

        let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                  outputSettings: settingsAssistant.videoSettings,
                                                  sourceFormatHint: formatDescription)

        guard videoFileWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) else {
            print("Could not add video writer input to video file writer.")
            return
        }

        videoFileWriter.add(videoWriterInput)

        guard videoFileWriter.startWriting() else {
            print("Video file writer not ready to write file.")
            return
        }

        videoFileWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(earliestRecordedSampleBuffer))

        videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: recordingClipQueue) {
            while videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                if self.backfillSampleBufferList.count > 0 {
                    let sampleBufferToAppend = self.backfillSampleBufferList.first!.deepCopy()
                    let appendSampleBufferSucceeded = videoWriterInput.append(sampleBufferToAppend)
                    if !appendSampleBufferSucceeded {
                        print("Failed to append sample buffer to asset writer input: \(videoFileWriter.error!)")
                        print("Video file writer status: \(videoFileWriter.status.rawValue)")
                    }

                    self.backfillSampleBufferList.remove(at: 0)
                } else {
                    videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                    videoFileWriter.finishWriting {
                        print("Saved clip to \(clipURL)")
                    }

                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
                       didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        guard let buffer = sampleBuffer else {
            print("Captured sample buffer was nil.")
            return
        }

        let sampleBufferCopy = buffer.deepCopy()

        backfillSampleBufferList.append(sampleBufferCopy)

        if backfillSizeInSeconds() > 3.0 {
            session.stopRunning()
            createClipFromBackfill()
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
                       didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        print("Sample buffer dropped.")
    }

}
```

CVPixelBuffer+Copy.swift:

```
import CoreVideo

extension CVPixelBuffer {
    func deepCopy() -> CVPixelBuffer {
        precondition(CFGetTypeID(self) == CVPixelBufferGetTypeID(), "deepCopy() cannot copy a non-CVPixelBuffer")

        var _copy : CVPixelBuffer?
        CVPixelBufferCreate(
            nil,
            CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self),
            CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self),
            CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(self),
            CVBufferGetAttachments(self, CVAttachmentMode.shouldPropagate),
            &_copy)

        guard let copy = _copy else {
            print("Pixel buffer copy was nil.")
            fatalError()
        }

        CVBufferPropagateAttachments(self, copy)
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(copy, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        let sourceBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(self)
        let copyBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(copy)
        memcpy(copyBaseAddress, sourceBaseAddress, CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self) * CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(self))

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(copy, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)

        return copy
    }
}
```

CMSampleBuffer+Copy.swift:

```
import CoreMedia

extension CMSampleBuffer {
    func deepCopy() -> CMSampleBuffer {
        let _pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self)
        guard let pixelBuffer = _pixelBuffer else {
            print("Pixel buffer to copy was nil.")
            fatalError()
        }
        let pixelBufferCopy = pixelBuffer.deepCopy()

        let _formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(self)
        guard let formatDescription = _formatDescription else {
            print("Format description to copy was nil.")
            fatalError()
        }

        var timingInfo = kCMTimingInfoInvalid
        let getTimingInfoResult = CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(self, 0, &timingInfo)
        guard getTimingInfoResult == noErr else {
            print("Could not get timing info to copy: \(getTimingInfoResult).")
            fatalError()
        }

        timingInfo.presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(self)

        var _copy : CMSampleBuffer?
        let createCopyResult = CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                  pixelBufferCopy,
                                                                  true,
                                                                  nil,
                                                                  nil,
                                                                  formatDescription,
                                                                  &timingInfo,
                                                                  &_copy);

        guard createCopyResult == noErr else {
            print("Error creating copy of sample buffer: \(createCopyResult).")
            fatalError()
        }

        guard let copy = _copy else {
            print("Copied sample buffer was nil.")
            fatalError()
        }

        return copy
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research and experimentation, it appears using AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor to append the CVPixelBuffers of the CMSampleBuffers I'm storing to the AVAssetWriterInput works without generating an error.

Below is the modified version of ViewController.swift implementation that uses AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor to append pixel buffers.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    private let recordingClipQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.recordingClipQueue")
    private let videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.videoDataOutputQueue")
    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private var backfillSampleBufferList = [CMSampleBuffer]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480

        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo);
        let videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput;

        do {
            videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating device input from video device: \(error).")
            return
        }

        guard session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
            print("Could not add video device input to capture session.")
            return
        }

        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)

        let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString : Int(kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA) ]
        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)

        guard session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) else {
            print("Could not add video data output to capture session.")
            return
        }

        session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        videoDataOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).isEnabled = true

        session.startRunning()
    }

    private func backfillSizeInSeconds() -> Double {
        if backfillSampleBufferList.count < 1 {
            return 0.0
        }

        let earliestSampleBuffer = backfillSampleBufferList.first!
        let latestSampleBuffer = backfillSampleBufferList.last!

        let earliestSampleBufferPTS = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(earliestSampleBuffer).value
        let latestSampleBufferPTS = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(latestSampleBuffer).value
        let timescale = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(latestSampleBuffer).timescale

        return Double(latestSampleBufferPTS - earliestSampleBufferPTS) / Double(timescale)
    }

    private func createClipFromBackfill() {
        guard backfillSampleBufferList.count > 0 else {
            print("createClipFromBackfill() called before any samples were recorded.")
            return
        }

        let clipURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:
            NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] +
            "/recorded_clip.mp4")

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: clipURL.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: clipURL.path)
            } catch {
                print("Could not delete existing clip file: \(error).")
            }
        }

        var _videoFileWriter: AVAssetWriter?
        do {
            _videoFileWriter = try AVAssetWriter(url: clipURL, fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4)
        } catch {
            print("Could not create video file writer: \(error).")
            return
        }

        guard let videoFileWriter = _videoFileWriter else {
            print("Video writer was nil.")
            return
        }

        let settingsAssistant = AVOutputSettingsAssistant(preset: AVOutputSettingsPreset640x480)!

        guard videoFileWriter.canApply(outputSettings: settingsAssistant.videoSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
            print("Video file writer could not apply video output settings.")
            return
        }

        let earliestRecordedSampleBuffer = backfillSampleBufferList.first!

        let _formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(earliestRecordedSampleBuffer)
        guard let formatDescription = _formatDescription else {
            print("Earliest recording pixel buffer format description was nil.")
            return
        }

        let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                  outputSettings: settingsAssistant.videoSettings,
                                                  sourceFormatHint: formatDescription)

        guard videoFileWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) else {
            print("Could not add video writer input to video file writer.")
            return
        }

        videoFileWriter.add(videoWriterInput)

        let pixelAdapterBufferAttributes = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCMPixelFormat_32BGRA) ]
        let pixelAdapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
                                                                sourcePixelBufferAttributes: pixelAdapterBufferAttributes)

        guard videoFileWriter.startWriting() else {
            print("Video file writer not ready to write file.")
            return
        }

        videoFileWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(earliestRecordedSampleBuffer))

        videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: recordingClipQueue) {
            while videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                if self.backfillSampleBufferList.count > 0 {
                    let sampleBufferToAppend = self.backfillSampleBufferList.first!.deepCopy()
                    let appendSampleBufferSucceeded = pixelAdapter.append(CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBufferToAppend)!,
                                                                          withPresentationTime: CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBufferToAppend))
                    if !appendSampleBufferSucceeded {
                        print("Failed to append sample buffer to asset writer input: \(videoFileWriter.error!)")
                        print("Video file writer status: \(videoFileWriter.status.rawValue)")
                    }

                    self.backfillSampleBufferList.remove(at: 0)
                } else {
                    videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                    videoFileWriter.finishWriting {
                        print("Saving clip to \(clipURL)")
                    }

                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
                       didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        guard let buffer = sampleBuffer else {
            print("Captured sample buffer was nil.")
            return
        }

        let sampleBufferCopy = buffer.deepCopy()

        backfillSampleBufferList.append(sampleBufferCopy)

        if backfillSizeInSeconds() > 3.0 {
            session.stopRunning()
            createClipFromBackfill()
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
                       didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        print("Sample buffer dropped.")
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you be more spot on the changes you made in class compared to the code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this while trying to synthesize videos. I finally figured out that `-[AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:]` only works on device (as of iOS 11.2.6 anyway) if the underlying pixel buffer is backed by an `IOSurface`.

If you modify your `CVPixelBuffer.deepCopy()` method to include the `(id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey: @{}` key-value pair in the attributes dictionary you pass to `CVPixelBufferCreate`, it'll probably work.

Comment: Adding the flag `kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey` with an empty dictionary fixed my issue. I was having a similar issue, but using an `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` wasn't an option: for me, it was returning the error `-12902` (`kVTParameterErr`), which didn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks, I was scratching my head for about 4 hours, comparing captured from camera CMSampleBuffer vs my generated CMSampleBuffer, getting the same error.  This works perfect!

Comment: It fixed my issue and now appendSampleBuffer is called. But after sometime the application terminates with following error Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue. While I am calling CVBufferRelease(lBuffer.pixelBufferRef);
                CFRelease(lBuffer.sampleBuffer); same way after turning on writing as I was calling them before.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into issues with the same error codes when creating `CVPixelBuffer`s and `CMSampleBuffer`s manually to create a video with individual frames rendered by `CoreGraphics`. I could solve the problem by using a `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` instead, like you suggested in your own answer. For some reason, this was only needed when the code was run on an actual device. On the simulator, manually creating the buffers worked fine.

I noticed that the same error codes `AVFoundationErrorDomain Code -11800` and `NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code -12780` can also occur for other reasons, for example:

- There exists already a file at the destination URL provided to `AVAssetWriter`
- The destination URL is not a file URL (it must be created with `URL.init(fileURLWithPath:)` and not with `URL.init(string:)`).

(Posting this for the sake of completeness, your code already handles this correctly.)

Comment: More related reasons: a) The directory part of the filename being too long – which can happen fairly easily inside iOS containers. b) Lowercasing the base path, e.g. temporary directory path, since APFS is case-sensitive on iOS